# Run an untrusted C program in a sandbox in Linux that prevents it from opening files, forking, etc.?

Tags: linux, sandbox

I was wondering if there exists a way to run an untrusted C program under a sandbox in Linux. Something that would prevent the program from opening files, or network connections, or forking, exec, etc?

It would be a small program, a homework assignment, that gets uploaded to a server and has unit tests executed on it. So the program would be short lived.

Comment: Is this like a single C program you need to run 1 time for 5 minutes, or something you need to run constantly?

Comment: It would be a small program that gets uploaded and has unit tests executed on it. So the program would be short lived.

Comment: What distribution is the system using? Some distributions have ready-made tools for sandboxing. Does your system have any security model like SELinux or AppArmor enabled ?

Comment: I'm using Fedora 13. I'm looking into SELinux Sandbox policy. I'm wondering what other options exist.

Comment: If your system already has a security model enabled (since it's Fedora it will probably be SELinux) it's recommended to use that one. I have not tried the Fedora Sandbox policy, but I am under the impression that it's quite well made.

Comment: Similar Qs on sandboxing/jailing processes in Linux or Unix:

* http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/6433/4319

* http://stackoverflow.com/q/3859710/94687

* http://stackoverflow.com/q/4410447/94687

* http://stackoverflow.com/q/1019707/94687

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I have used [Systrace](http://www.systrace.org/) to sandbox untrusted programs both interactively and in automatic mode. It has a [`ptrace()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ptrace)-based backend which allows its use on a Linux system without special privileges, as well as a far faster and more poweful backend which requires patching the kernel.

It is also possible to create a sandbox on Unix-like systems using [`chroot(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chroot), although that is not quite as easy or secure. [Linux Containers](http://lxc.sourceforge.net/) and [FreeBSD jails](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD_jail) are a better alternative to chroot. Another alternative on Linux is to use a security framework like [SELinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux) or [AppArmor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppArmor), which is what I would propose for production systems.

We would be able to help you more if you told as what exactly it is that you want to do.

**EDIT:**

Systrace would work for your case, but I think that something based on the [Linux Security Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Security_Modules) like AppArmor or SELinux is a more standard, and thus preferred, alternative, depending on your distribution.

**EDIT 2:**

While [`chroot(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chroot) is available on most (all?) Unix-like systems, it has quite a few issues:

- It can be broken out of. If you are going to actually compile or run untrusted C programs on your system, you are especially vulnerable to this issue. And if your students are anything like mine, someone WILL try to break out of the jail.
- You have to create a full independent filesystem hierarchy with everything that is necessary for your task. You do not have to have a compiler in the chroot, but anything that is required to run the compiled programs should be included. While there are utilities that help with this, it's still not trivial.
- You have to maintain the chroot. Since it is independent, the chroot files will not be updated along with your distribution. You will have to either recreate the chroot regularly, or include the necessary update tools in it, which would essentially require that it be a full-blown Linux distribution. You will also have to keep system and user data (passwords, input files e.t.c.) synchronized with the host system.
- `chroot()` only protects the filesystem. It does not prevent a malicious program from opening network sockets or a badly-written one from sucking up every available resource.

The resource usage problem is common among all alternatives. [Filesystem quotas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_quota) will prevent programs from filling the disk. Proper [`ulimit`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html) ([`setrlimit()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/setrlimit) in C) settings can protect against memory overuse and any fork bombs, as well as put a stop to CPU hogs. [`nice(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nice) can lower the priority of those programs so that the computer can be used for any tasks that are deemed more important with no problem.

Comment: systrace worked for me for simple, programs, but got stuck indefinitely when GNU as(1) as run by GCC. So I gave up on it. It's an unfixed bug in systrace: http://forum.soft32.com/linux/strace-wait4-pending-SIGALRM-ftopict484715.html

Comment: Is there a way to ensure that shared memory, message queues, and semaphores are not shared between sandboxed processes?

Comment: The systrace link is broken.

Comment: What about Firejail? You have not to maintain the fs anymore using it.

Answer (score 18):

I wrote an [overview of sandboxing techniques in Linux](http://web.archive.org/web/20141122112516/http://blog.technologyofcontent.com/2011/04/sandboxing-for-multi-tenant-applications) recently. I think your easiest approach would be to use Linux containers (lxc) if you dont mind about forking and so on, which don't really matter in this environment. You can give the process a read only root file system, an isolated loopback network connection, and you can still kill it easily and set memory limits etc.

Seccomp is going to be a bit difficult, as the code cannot even allocate memory.

Selinux is the other option, but I think it might be more work than a container.

Answer (score 8):

Firejail is one of the most comprehensive tools to do that - it support seccomp, filesystem containers, capabilities and more:

https://firejail.wordpress.com/features-3/

Comment: This answer is excellent, it really deserves more upvotes considering that firejail is actively maintained with great documentation, encompasses most if not all of the other answers and is designed to be relatively easy to use.

Comment: Does `firejail` affects the CPU runtime of a program?

Answer (score 7):

You can use Qemu to test assignments quickly. This procedure below takes less than 5 seconds on my 5 year old laptop.

Let's assume the student has to develop a program that takes unsigned ints, each on their own line, until a line with "-1" arrives. The program should then average all the ints and output "Average: %f". Here's how you could test program completely isolated:

1. First, get `root.bin` from Jslinux, we'll use that as the userland (it has the tcc C-compiler):

   `wget https://github.com/levskaya/jslinux-deobfuscated/raw/master/root.bin`
2. We want to put the student's submission in `root.bin`, so set up the loop device:

   `sudo losetup /dev/loop0 root.bin`

   (you could use fuseext2 for this too, but it's not very stable. If it stabilizes, you won't need root for any of this)
3. Make an empty directory:

   `mkdir mountpoint`
4. Mount `root.bin`:

   `sudo mount /dev/loop0 mountpoint`
5. Enter the mounted filesystem:

   `cd mountpoint`.
6. Fix rights:

   `` sudo chown -R `whoami` . ``
7. `mkdir -p etc/init.d`
8. `vi etc/init.d`:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   cd /root
   echo READY 2>&1 > /dev/ttyS0
   tcc assignment.c 2>&1 > /dev/ttyS0
   ./a.out 2>&1 > /dev/ttyS0
   ```
9. `chmod +x etc/init.d/rcS`
10. Copy the submission to the VM:

    `cp ~/student_assignment.c root/assignment.c`
11. Exit the VM's root FS:

    `cd ..`
12. `sudo umount mountpoint`
13. Now the image is ready, we just need to run it. It will compile and run the submission after booting.
14. `mkfifo /tmp/guest_output`
15. Open a seperate terminal and start listening for guest output:

    `dd if=/tmp/guest_output bs=1`
16. In another terminal:

    `qemu-system-i386 -kernel vmlinuz-3.5.0-27-generic -initrd root.bin -monitor stdio -nographic -serial pipe:/tmp/guestoutput`
    (I just used the Ubuntu kernel here, but many kernels will work)
17. When the guest output shows "READY", you can send keys to the VM from the qemu prompt.
    For example, to test this assignment, you could do

    ```
    (qemu) sendkey 1
    (qemu) sendkey 4
    (qemu) sendkey ret
    (qemu) sendkey 1
    (qemu) sendkey 0
    (qemu) sendkey ret
    (qemu) sendkey minus
    (qemu) sendkey 1
    (qemu) sendkey ret
    ```
18. Now `Average = 12.000000` should appear on the guest output pipe. If it doesn't, the student failed.
19. Quit qemu: `quit`

A program passing the test is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14424295/309483. Just use `tcclib.h` instead of `stdio.h`.

Answer (score 5):

Try [User-mode Linux](http://user-mode-linux.sf.net). It has about 1% performance overhead for CPU-intensive jobs, but it may be 6 times slower for I/O-intensive jobs.

Answer (score 3):

Running it inside a virtual machine should offer you all the security and restrictions you want.

[QEMU](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page) would be a good fit for that and all the work (downloading the application, updating the disk image, starting QEMU, running the application inside it, and saving the output for later retrieval) could be scripted for automated tests runs.

Comment: I don't know about the OP, but launching a VM per test program would be unacceptable in many cases. In my environment (I'm a TA) there can be as many as 200 students submitting 10-12 programs each within a 2-hour period. No program runs for more than 10sec CPU-time, but when the submissions pile up we get turn-around times of 15min or more. Introducing a VM for each program would push the CPU-time to 60sec or more per program and I don't want to think about the turn-around times at all. Maybe a VM per session, but no way we could do that per-program...

Comment: @thkala This is a good point. I like the idea of QEMU but starting a VM for each submission is not good.

Comment: Well, in that case, keep the same VM running all the time.

Comment: Could you do something using a snapshot of a vm that's all booted and ready to compile & run code?  FYI, vm's are not necessarily immune to piercing.  You could also build a hardware version of this - a small system that boots a resume image off read-only media or over the network and provides output via network or serial, then gets rebooted for the next.  There've been some quick booting advances that get linux up in a few seconds.

Comment: @thkala: That means you'd need less than 3 seconds per submission if you ran them serially. The approach I posted probably takes around 3 seconds on a modern machine (serially). If you parallelize (which you might as well) it would be fast enough.

Answer (score 3):

When it goes about sanboxing based on ptrace (strace) check-out:

"**sydbox**" sandbox and "**pinktrace**" programming library ( it's C99 but there are bindings to python and ruby as far as I know).

Collected links related to topic:

http://www.diigo.com/user/wierzowiecki/sydbox

(sorry that not direct links, but no enough reputation points yet)

Answer (score 3):

seccomp and seccomp-bpf accomplish this with the least effort: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/prctl/seccomp_filter.txt

Answer (score -2):

ok thanks to all the answers they helped ME a lot. But i would suggest none of them as an solution for the person who asked the original question. All mentioned tools require to much work for the purpose to test students code as a teacher,tutor,prof. The best way in this case would be in my opinion virtualbox. Ok, its emulates an complete x68-system and has nothing to do with the meaning of sandboxing in this way but if i imagine my programming teacher it would be the best for him. So "apt-get install virtualbox" on debian based systems, all others head over to http://virtualbox.org/ , create a vm, add an iso, click install, wait some time and be lucky. It will be much easier to use as to set up user-mode-linux or doing some heavy strace stuff...

And if you have fears about your students hacking you i guess you have an authority problem and a solution for that would be threaten them that you will sue the living daylights out of them if you can prove just one bite of maleware in the work they give you...

Also if there is a class and 1% of it is as good as he could do such things, dont bore them with such simple tasks and give them some big ones where they have to code some more. Integrative learning is best for everyone so dont relay on old deadlocked structures...

And of cause, never use the same computer for important things (like writing attestations and exams), that you are using for things like browsing the web and testing software.

Use an off line computer for important things and an on line computer for all other things.

However to everyone else who isnt a paranoid teacher (dont want to offend anybody, i am just the opinion that you should learn the basics about security and our society before you start being a programmers teacher...)

... where was i ... for everyone else:

happy hacking !!