# Creating temporary sandbox environment in unix

Tags: unix, sandbox

Just wondering is there any way to create a temporary sandbox environment for running commands?

My requirement is that i am hosting a webservice in unix and i need to execute a commanline tool to return output to the webservice client. since i am passing the values received from the client to the commanline tool, i would like to execute the commands in sandboxed environment.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249063/how-can-i-run-an-untrusted-c-program-in-a-sandbox-in-linux

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure but, you can try to use the "chroot" command to create new "root" enviroment, for example,

If you have the directory structure and you want to "protect" the "license" file,

```
/
/etc
 + license
/bin
 + ls
/lib
 + ...
```

You can create a chroot enviroment as

```
itily@openzooey:~$ mkdir chroot_example
itily@openzooey:~$ cd chroot_example/
itily@openzooey:~/chroot_example$ mkdir -p usr/lib lib bin etc
itily@openzooey:~/chroot_example$ cd bin/
itily@openzooey:~/chroot_example/bin$ cp /bin/ls .
itily@openzooey:~/chroot_example/bin$ ldd ls 
        libsec.so.1 =>   /lib/libsec.so.1
        libnvpair.so.1 =>        /lib/libnvpair.so.1
        libcmdutils.so.1 =>      /lib/libcmdutils.so.1
        libcurses.so.1 =>        /lib/libcurses.so.1
        libc.so.1 =>     /lib/libc.so.1
        libavl.so.1 =>   /lib/libavl.so.1
        libidmap.so.1 =>         /usr/lib/libidmap.so.1
        libnsl.so.1 =>   /lib/libnsl.so.1
        libuutil.so.1 =>         /lib/libuutil.so.1
        libmp.so.2 =>    /lib/libmp.so.2
        libmd.so.1 =>    /lib/libmd.so.1
        libm.so.2 =>     /lib/libm.so.2
```

Now populate the "shared lib" required by the *ls* command (using the *ldd* we know which are the required shared libs

```
itily@openzooey:~/chroot_example/bin$ ldd ls |awk '{print "cp "$3" lib/"}'
cp /lib/libsec.so.1 lib/
cp /lib/libnvpair.so.1 lib/
cp /lib/libcmdutils.so.1 lib/
cp /lib/libcurses.so.1 lib/
cp /lib/libc.so.1 lib/
cp /lib/libavl.so.1 lib/
cp /usr/lib/libidmap.so.1 lib/
cp /lib/libnsl.so.1 lib/
cp /lib/libuutil.so.1 lib/
cp /lib/libmp.so.2 lib/
cp /lib/libmd.so.1 lib/
cp /lib/libm.so.2 lib/
```

Now we need to copy to our new "lib" and *usr/lib* directory

```
itily@openzooey:~/chroot_example/bin$ cd ..
itily@openzooey:~/chroot_example$ ldd /bin/ls |awk '{print "cp "$3" lib/"}'|bash 
itily@openzooey:~/chroot_example$ ls -ltr
total 9
drwxr-xr-x   2 itily    staff          2 dic 22 14:37 etc
drwxr-xr-x   2 itily    staff          3 dic 22 14:37 bin
drwxr-xr-x   2 itily    staff         14 dic 22 14:38 lib

itily@openzooey:~/chroot_example$ cp /usr/lib/libidmap.so.1 usr/lib/
itily@openzooey:~/chroot_example$ cp /usr/lib/ld.so.1 usr/lib/
itily@openzooey:~/chroot_example$ cd lib/
itily@openzooey:~/chroot_example/lib$ ls -l
total 7615
-rwxr-xr-x   1 itily    staff      14044 dic 22 14:38 libavl.so.1
-rwxr-xr-x   1 itily    staff    1721400 dic 22 14:38 libc.so.1
-rwxr-xr-x   1 itily    staff      26748 dic 22 14:38 libcmdutils.so.1
-rwxr-xr-x   1 itily    staff     293876 dic 22 14:38 libcurses.so.1
-rwxr-xr-x   1 itily    staff      97852 dic 22 14:38 libidmap.so.1
-rwxr-xr-x   1 itily    staff     398704 dic 22 14:38 libm.so.2
-rwxr-xr-x   1 itily    staff      87164 dic 22 14:38 libmd.so.1
-rwxr-xr-x   1 itily    staff      25140 dic 22 14:38 libmp.so.2
-rwxr-xr-x   1 itily    staff     648776 dic 22 14:38 libnsl.so.1
-rwxr-xr-x   1 itily    staff      74776 dic 22 14:38 libnvpair.so.1
-rwxr-xr-x   1 itily    staff      97500 dic 22 14:38 libsec.so.1
-rwxr-xr-x   1 itily    staff      49556 dic 22 14:38 libuutil.so.1
itily@openzooey:~/chroot_example/lib$ cd ..
```

So, the final structure is

```
itily@openzooey:~/chroot_example$ ls -l
total 12
drwxr-xr-x   2 itily    staff          3 dic 22 14:37 bin
drwxr-xr-x   2 itily    staff          5 ene 10 20:43 etc
drwxr-xr-x   2 itily    staff         14 ene 10 20:48 lib
drwxr-xr-x   3 itily    staff          3 ene 10 20:40 usr
```

Also you need the group, passwd and other files

```
itily@openzooey:~/chroot_example$ echo "this is a test" > etc/license
itily@openzooey:~/chroot_example$ cd etc/
itily@openzooey:~/chroot_example/etc$ cat /etc/group |grep staff > group
itily@openzooey:~/chroot_example/etc$ cat /etc/passwd |grep itily > passwd
```

Now you can run the *chroot* command, but if you try to run as *non root* you will get the error

```
itily@openzooey:~$ chroot chroot_example bin/ls /etc
chroot: cannot change root directory to chroot_example: Not owner
```

So, you need to run as *root*

```
itily@openzooey:~$ pfexec chroot chroot_example /bin/ls -l /etc
total 6
-rw-r--r--   1 101      10            11 Jan 10 19:43 group
-rw-r--r--   1 101      10            18 Jan 10 19:42 license
-rw-r--r--   1 101      10            49 Jan 10 19:43 passwd
```

I hope it's what you are looking for ...

Urko,

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say which Unix.  Solaris zones do that easily.  Here's an example how to set one up:

http://www.solarisinternals.com/wiki/index.php/Zones

Comment: basically i am looking for centOS, thats what my hosting provider has. but its lice to know that solaris has such a nice thing...

Comment: There's similar options for other OSes, but I haven't used them.  A couple I've read about are Linux-VServer and OpenVZ.

Answer (score 1):

I routinely develop in sandboxes in Debian Linux and like to use chroots so that I don't destroy my host machine in case I do something stupid by accident (which happens a lot).  I put together a set of scripts for Debian and Ubuntu for me to create chroots (both cross-distro and x86 in x86-64) which you may find helpful.

https://github.com/vtonehundred/vroot