# How can i read a line of numbers from stdin & compute their average?

Tags: c

How may I count & extract a number of elements from stdin?

For instance, len() is easily available in Python, but not in C?

Im trying to compute an average, when user enters for eg:
1 3 5 7 8 10 11 -1

I've tried the following:

```
while (user_input != -1)
{
    total   += user_input;
    scanf ("%d", &user_input);

    //cannot work               
    average = total /  ...
}       
printf("Average = %f\n", average);
```

Comment: You should take in input a raw line and parse it.

Comment: The question makes no sense..

Comment: if you're looking to count the amount of times you were in the while loop. do it manually. (just like you did with total, just add 1 instead of user_input).

Comment: How'd you compare something like `C's scanf()` and `Python's len()`? I guess there are some oompa loompas working here around...

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to maintain a counter to do what you're trying to do. its just `int counter = 0;` and in the loop: `counter++`

```
int counter = 0;
while (user_input != -1)
{
    total   += user_input;
    counter ++;
    scanf ("%d", &user_input);
}       
average = total / counter;
printf("Average = %f\n", average);
```

obviously, you'll have to check if `scanf()` returned atleast 1

--- EDIT ---
the following program(that corresponds to the previous program) is VALID and works as required. People who do not understand how `scanf()` works, should stay the damn out:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int total = 0;
   float average = 0.0f;
   int userinput = 0;
   int counter = -1;
   while(userinput != -1){
      counter ++;
      if(scanf("%d",&userinput) == 1 && userinput != -1){
         total += userinput;
      }
   }
   average = ((float)total/(float)counter);
   printf("Average = %f", average);
   return 0;
}
```

Input: `10 20 30 40 50 60 -1`
Output: `Average = 35`

Comment: -1 : Clearly, this answer is no longer relevant after OPs Q edit & the comments  from OP. In short it answers something which OP doesn't ask for. Also, it is not going to be useful to anyone who stumbles upon this answer in future.Please edit it to answer what the OP asks and I shall remove the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

From your modified question & comments, it seems what you really want to do is read a line of input from the user and then extract numbers from that line of input.
The answer is you cannot do that using `scanf`, You need to use `fgets` to read the line from `stdin` and then you need to extract numbers from that read line. Here is a,
 **[Quick sample program](http://ideone.com/KacsyH)**:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char line[1024], *beg, *end;
    long readvalue;
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin)) 
    {
        beg = line;
        for (beg = line; ; beg = end) 
        {
            readvalue = strtol(beg, &end, 10);
            if (beg == end)
                break;
                printf("[%d]",readvalue);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Input:**

```
1 3 5 7 8 10 11 -1
```

**Output:**

```
[1][3][5][7][8][10][11][-1]
```

Comment: I would give this a -1, how can it count the no. of elements IN the `scanf()`? Its only the no. of elements successfully returned IIRC

Comment: @Aniket: Have you **read** the answer? Important lesson for you, **Read** then comment and not the other way round.

Comment: @Aniket Not quite. "Upon successful completion, these functions shall return the number of successfully matched and assigned input items; this number can be zero in the event of an early matching failure" - from the documentation [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/fscanf.html).

Comment: @Alok Save: ty. i just edited my qn. suppose that the user input was: 1 3 5 7 8 9 -1 in a single line, how may i still compute the average?

Comment: @brainsfrying: Does the user enter 1 3 5 7 8 9 -1 at once? or does the user enter a single number on each iteration?

Comment: @AlokSave: Yes, all at once. Hence I have to compute the average from that single line of inputs.

Comment: @AlokSave: Do you have a sample? As in for this case?