# How to sandbox a go program

Tags: go, sandbox

Q: Is there a way to sandbox a Go program?
A: Yes.  See [GAE w/ Go](http://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/) or [play.golang.org](http://play.golang.org)

How is this done?

In my particular case I'd like to allow untrusted extensions written in Go.  I imagine the Go Playground is exactly what I'd need.  Is it open source? Or is there at least some documentation on how to build a similar service?

#### note:

[code.google.com/p/go-playground](http://code.google.com/p/go-playground) is the source for the Go Playground editor.  But the sandbox is hidden behind a POST to `http://golang.org/compile?output=json`.

Comment: This isn't really a go question. Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249063/how-can-i-run-an-untrusted-c-program-in-a-sandbox-in-linux will prove helpful?

Comment: I think there is a Go specific answer.  In particular Go design was influenced by the need to sandbox it on GAE.  But I can't find a description of how it's done.

Comment: Do you have a citation for the idea that the Go runtime was designed to be sandboxed?

Comment: @JonathanFeinberg, I've been looking and can't seem to find any.  I was conflating Go's design for safe code (e.g. array bounds checking, no pointer arithmetic) with the Go Playground and GAE's sandboxing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to http://blog.golang.org/playground , the sandbox in the go playground uses NaCl to limit CPU and RAM usage.  The code for it has been merged into go version 1.3.

Answer (score 12):

The playground sandboxing technology is, AFAIK, not open sourced. One of the reasons for this is, I think, that disclosing publicly the implementation details would make any attack attempts substantially easier.

I would suggest to, if rolling your own sandbox, to provide fake/empty/limited versions of the {unsafe,runtime,net,os,syscall} packages and disallow GOMAXPROCS above 1. But the design must be tailored to the very your definition of a sandbox. File access yes/no/restricted? Networking yes/no/restricted? etc... Last but not least, one should probably disable CGO, assembler code and probably even build tags.

Consider the above list is incomplete.

Comment: It looks like you're correct.  Russ Cox works for Google and wrote this about [sanboxing Go](http://research.swtch.com/gorace).

Comment: Besides doing the above I would also put each application in its own linux cgroup/namespace-based container, or less ideally chroot.