# How to create a sandbox environment in C++?

Tags: c++, linux, sandbox, dynamic-library

Is there a way to create a sandbox environment inside C++ where you can either:
- Run processes in
- Load Dynamic Libraries in (Linux)

Dynamic Libraries are preferred because the easy communication between the main process and the sand-boxed processes.

A sand-boxed process should not be able to put memory on the heap or interact with the Kernel / Operating System. Instead the main process will provide an interface to do these things.

Is there any way to do this? I could create a script interpreter but that'd take away a lot of the speed. I'd like to keep the speed loss minimal.

Comment: "Putting memory on the stack" is a fundamental operation in C-like languages. All C / C++ programs will use the stack.

Comment: @duskwuff heap*, I corrected it. :D

Comment: maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249063/how-can-i-run-an-untrusted-c-program-in-a-sandbox-in-linux

Comment: @Binero: That's really not a reasonable thing to expect of a program either. The stdio library (e.g, `printf()`) uses memory allocated on the heap for buffers.

Comment: Maybe [Qemu](http://www.qemu.org) could be useful (even if a bit overkill).

Comment: @duskwuff The main application will provider an interface for these things.

Answer (score -4):

You can use some software which provides sandbox environment. Use can provide memory limit, time limit etc. and other parameters to the application. I used a sandbox file when I created some online judge and needed to execute c++ files of other users in a limited environment.

Comment: All you've done here is restate the question. You haven't actually provided an answer.