# Execute a code with full monitoring in linux

Tags: linux, testing, profiling, sandbox, profiler

I need to test some projects that are written in different languages and using different frameworks(Python, C#, Java,.. Django, Flask,...) but i can not trust projects, so i need to run them in an isolated environment so that i could fully observe them.

There are maybe many approaches to this task. For example i can run them in a virtual box. But this solution has a lot of problems like performance issue, installing all dependencies in virtual box and so on.

Is there another solution with following features for this task in Linux?

#### Main Features:

- View all file systems that application uses.
- View network communications (Something like Google chrome's network panel)
- Independent of language

#### Optional Features:

- Profile project(View memory usage, CPU usage and.. of project)

Comment: This might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4249063/507519

Comment: Thanks for your link, it's not exactly what i want but if i couldn't find another solution it might help.